# How do I get the remaining divs to fill up space horizontally in a parent div?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   <div id="labelDiv"></div>
   <div class="contentDiv"></div>
   <div class="contentDiv"></div>
   <div class="contentDiv"></div>
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

`labelDiv` is always a fixed size.  In this case, 30px.  `parentDiv` is set to a width of 75%.  There can be 1 to any number of `contentDiv`. What I want is to evenly space out the `contentDiv` objects.  I'm trying to do this all in CSS (2.1, if possible). I was able to write a quick jQuery function to equally space out the divs, but I don't feel like its the best solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are these floated left or displayed inline or something?

Comment: @Ruirize: No dice, it ended up floating all of the `contentDiv` objects, and didn't maintain any sort of width.  But I'll give you an upvote for a partial answer. :)

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I've tried both `float: left` and `display: inline` for the objects, but it doesn't seem to maintain the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: table; table-layout: fixed` can do this.

This *is* all CSS 2.1 as requested, but check the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/css-table) - it works everywhere except IE6/7.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Ec8Tw/

**CSS:**

```
#parentDiv {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #444
}
#parentDiv > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed #f0f
}
#labelDiv {
    width: 30px;
    background: #ccc
}
```