# <li> elements with adapted width

Tags: css, width, html-lists

I'm wondering if it is possible to do this in CSS, without javascript:

A list of N `<li>` items, with display inline, equal width, and the width of the all equal to the width of the container

I can have 3 `<li>` items, in this case the `<li>` width will be 33%, or I can have 4 `<li>` items, then the li width will be 25%.

Comment: Yes. Specify the width for the parent and remove all padding and margin from `li`.

Comment: @bobek: I think you didn't fully comprehend his question. Equal widths, thus each element's width depending on the number of siblings it has.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099106/how-do-i-get-the-remaining-divs-to-fill-up-space-horizontally-in-a-parent-div/7099160#7099160 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038592/html-css-create-self-expanding-dynamic-div/7038891#7038891 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310632/html-list-element-sharing-the-parent-width-into-equal-parts/6311029#6311029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with CSS3 [flex boxes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/), as demonstrated in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KggeP/) (for webkit browsers only). There are [other browser custom properties](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) that would make this work for recent versions of Firefox and IE. If you need something that works for Opera or older versions of IE then there is a JavaScript library called [Flexie](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie) which might work.

Credit to [The CSS3 Flexible Box Layout (flexbox)](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/the_css3_flexible_box_layout_flexbox/) for the information on the browser support.

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    width:200px;
}

li {
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    border:1px dashed grey;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: this solution works but I need a cross browser solution, and with table-cell (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038592/html-css-create-self-expanding-dynamic-div/7038891#7038891) I can achieve it perfectly as well (cross browser except for IE7...)

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect example for usage of **`display: table`**.
Works in modern browsers and IE8+...
[Support chart](http://caniuse.com/#search=table%20display)
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web5me/kwRwm/)

css:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; /* optional, for equal spacing */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; /* or similar, if needed */
}
```

html:

```
<ul>
   <li>foo</li>
   <li>bar</li>
   <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, with a limited number of possibilities. In CSS3 you can't do it for an arbitrary number of columns, though. You may be able to in CSS4; I don't know yet.

```
li {
    display: inline;
}

/* 1 column */
li:first-child:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}

/* 2 columns */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(2):last-child {
    width: 50%;
}

/* 3 columns */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
li:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(3):last-child {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

/* 4 columns */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
li:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3),
li:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(4):last-child {
    width: 25%;
}
```

I hope you get the idea. Do you want to do this? I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `li`s are generated from some server-side code, you can use the following "trick":

```
// in the markup add a class to the UL based on the count of messages
<ul class="col<%= echo count(lis) %>">
...

// and in the CSS
// (notice you have to use display: inline-block, as inline doesn't allow you to
// specify a width)

li { display: inline-block; }
.col3 li { width: 33.3%; }
.col4 li { width: 25%; }
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a standard left-floated list and you can (or must) set display to inline to avoid IE6 doubling a possibly existing margin-left.

Assuming you have a static page, you can set your list up like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="listLR col3 clearfix">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
listLR {
  width: 100%; // important for IE!
}

listLR > li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

col3 > li {
  width: 33.33%;
}
col4 > li {
  width: 25%;
} //and so on
```

The use of a clearfix-class is demonstrated [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)